# NSProcessInfo returns different PATH than "echo $PATH"

Tags: macos, cocoa, environment-variables

I am trying to programatically figure out whether there is a specific binary in the system PATH. To get the environment I used both

```
NSString* path = [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"PATH"];
```

and

```
NSString* path2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: getenv("PATH")];
```

both yielding the same result, in both cases different then `echo $PATH` in console. Both *path* and *path2* does not contain paths set via */etc/paths.d*, so the question is how to get the the environment PATH as returned from console programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSProcessInfo will just access information about current process. For example below i am executing the same echo $PATH command in cocoa and am getting the same output which NSProcessInfo is displaying. So in the terminal when you execute the same command. You will get different ouput. Because it is showing the path of current process in terminal. If you want to see the same output of both you can execute this command in terminal **launchctl getenv PATH** which will be equivalent to [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"PATH"];

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/bash"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", @"echo $PATH",nil]];
NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
```

Comment: Thanks Hussain, your answer did not exactly answered my question, but led me to a correct solution. So, if one wants to get the PATH from the application it needs to be set in `/private/etc/launchd.conf` via `setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:your_path_goes_here`, `/etc/paths.d` solution is for console only.